# Why dup(2) listening sockets in multiple threaded servers?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, posix

I know programmers are often not so easy with threads and parallel programming, so this is a question for experts on the matter in priority.

There seems to be a relatively accepted but unknown good practice of calling dup(2) on listening sockets for threaded server applications. I understand the general principle of "share nothing" threads for peace of mind avoiding race conditions.

My question is : if the kernel already does mutual exclusion on accept(2) return values, exactly why is it interesting at all to dup(2) the listening socket ?

In case it is really an improvement, when should the socket be dup(2)-ed : after bind(2) or after listen(2) ?

Comment: Couldn't find a mention of this practice in a quick search. Looks rather pointless to me. `dup` only creates a new integer handle and duplicates a couple of relatively insignificant bit flags (or just one), the *open file description* which is the bulk of file/socket data remains shared.

Comment: I guess it might be related to close(2) race condition ?

Comment: Well normally a server doesn't close a listening socket, but if it needs to for some reason, then maybe duping it could be reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Yes kernel ensure that only one process/thread will be served in concurrent calls to `accept`. If you want do use it correctly, then you need to do it after `bind` and `listen`. After `bind` because you want to share a bound server socket... After `listen` to correctly configure the backlog for everybody.

Now it is a matter of design: you may prefer to have a single accepting thread dispatching the work among a pool of other threads (then you need to manage a pool by yourself), or have concurrent accepting threads and put the burden on the system. The first is more complex to set up but let you have a finer control on balancing. The second is much more straightforward but doesn't give you any control on the balancing.

Comment: Insightful, but still why dup(2) ?

Comment: Maybe because in case of thread termination, who can decide to close? If each thread has its own descriptor, code is much simpler? Using `dup` is certainly not mandatory.